# Change UIImageView Image path

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I'm completely new to objective-c and iOS programming with it. I am displaying a UIImageView with a default image path I set via storyboard. Now, I am trying to change the image to a different image, by changing the path to a different one.

I think I have set everything up so that I can programmatically manipulate the class (`IBOutlet`, `@property`, allocing, etc), but perhaps I am doing something wrong there. Otherwise, I am changing the image path via:

```
IMG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"s.png"];
```

Is this correct? If so, here is the other piece of relevant code in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _IMG = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
}
```

In the `@interface` part of my .h file:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *IMG;
```

And then the rest of my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *IMG;
```

Does anyone see anything incorrect? Thanks, I am a complete beginner so I apologize if this is an extremely basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, get rid of this line from your .h (you don't need it as you are declaring a property):

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *IMG;
```

Next, check that you have wired up your `IBOutlet` property to the `UIImageView` in Interface Builder (hold down CTRL and click on your `UIImageView`). Make sure there is an entry under Referencing Outlets. If not you will need to CTRL-drag to create one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard you dont need to alloc init your view, remove that code.

Comment: I removed that code, but it still does nothing. Thanks for the quick initial response!